# Missing Server Explorer right-click menu options in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, right-click, server-explorer

I've searched high and low for the answer to this and can find nothing on it.  I have installed VS 2010 pro edition on a virtual machine running MS XP Pro.  After connecting to my database, I can see all the tables, stored procedures, and functions just fine in the list.  However, when I rick-click on any of them, the options to create new/edit/run any of them are missing.

This is not the first time I've set up VS 2010.  I got a new laptop so reinstalled everything.  I changed no settings the first time I've set this up, and none this time.  I set up the connection to the databases the same way each time, and even looked at my old connection settings while I set up this installation.  The old installation had all of the right-click options, but this one does not.  I have tried going to `Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings` and tried `General Development Settings`, `Visual C# Development Settings`, and `Web Development` as the default collection of settings.  None of these worked.

I've looked through the settings and found nothing for the right-click menu.  It almost seems as if the database connection is open in a "read only" mode, but there doesn't seem to be a setting for that, so I don't think that is the case.  If anyone knows of any way to get these options to show up, I would greatly appreciate the input.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desperate to resolve this, I played around with the connection more.  I had originally chosen `Microsoft SQL Server` as the data source, and `.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB` as the Data Provider.  Evidently, the data provider was wrong.  After choosing `.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server`, it worked and I could see all of my right-click menu options.

Answer (score 2):

After I installed Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate), I accidentally uninstalled the SQL Server Data Tools which were installed together with VS, and after reinstalling them (by repairing the VS installation) the missing context menue options were back again.

Answer (score 0):

I have VS 2013 Ultimate installation. Along this version I installed SSTD BI. Everything was working perfect until I got the same issue. Right-click on tables or other folders displays only three options: copy, refresh, property. The tricky thing is that it's impossible to uninstall SSTD BI in Control Panel or install SSTD BI on top of previous installation. What helped me is repair installation of VS2013. Start your installation file and chose repair instead of installation. Couple hours and it's back to work.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded SSTD from here and it fixed my missing context menus

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501