# Cannot view stored procedure body in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

Using Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 to browse and query a SQL Server - there are some stored procedures for the database but I could not find a way to view the body of the stored procedure in Visual Studio.

From [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443.aspx) I tried a few hints, but I kept getting:

> The EXEC SQL construct or statement is not supported

Is there no way to do this from Visual Studio? I eventually solved my problem by installing SQL Management Studio; but I am hoping there is a way to do this in Visual Studio.

Update:

- I am not using a project - that is, I am not in an active project in Visual Studio; it is a simple case of browsing the database's objects and executing some queries from the Server Explorer window.
- The database server appears in the Server Explorer tree as `SQLEDB.SERVER-NAME.DBNAME`
- Visual Studio 2010 already has SP1 applied
- The same credentials allow me to view the body of the stored procedure when I connect via SQL Management Studio.
- SQL Server version is `SQL Server 8.0.2055 (8.0 SP4)`
- Workstation is running Windows XP Professional (so [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) cannot be installed)

Comment: You could add a new file of type "SQL File" to any project, and then type sp_helptext StoredProcName. Then connect to the desired server and run the script. If you have access, it'll return the body of the stored proc as a create script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open `Server Explorer`
- Drill down to your procedure.
- Right Click `Open`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saezsty3(v=vs.100).aspx

Or if you have [Sql Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) installed

- Open `SQL Server Object Explorer` from the view menu.
- Drill down to your procedure.
- Right Click `View Code`

Comment: There is no such menu option in Visual Studio 2010; and when I find my stored procedure in the Server Explorer tree and right click, there is no `'View Code'` option either.

Comment: When I right click on the stored procedure; I only have "Copy, Refresh, Properties".

Comment: How have you defined the connection to this server?

Comment: I clicked on the `Connect to Database` option in Server Explorer, and its `SQLOLEDB` connection.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011150/missing-server-explorer-right-click-menu-options-in-visual-studio-2010 help?

Comment: I tried the suggestion there, but when I changed my connection driver I got `This server version is not supported. You must have Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or later.`

Comment: `SQL Server 8.0.2055 (8.0 SP4)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Visual Studio (2013, in my case), using SQL Server (2005 or higher).  I select:

```
Tools | SQL Server > New Query...
```

and connect to the database server in which I'm interested.  Once connected, I can type:

```
sp_helptext MyStoredProcedureName
```

When I execute that command it returns the body of the given stored procedure.

Similarly, if I want to see the input and output parameters, I can execute:

```
sp_help MyStoredProcedureName
```

EDIT: You mentioned using the Server Explorer, but your question's subject indicates you want a way to do this in Visual Studio.  I often work in a query window in Visual Studio, without ever opening Server Explorer.  I find it clunky and prefer a simple query window for the simpler editing and queries I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have selected the database where the store procedures is deployed in the propoerties of the connection.

In the "Server Explorer" window edit the "Data connection" corresponding to the database and ensure the database is selected in the "Connect or enter a database name" section; the option "Select or enter a database name" must be selected and the database name must be seledted in the drop down list.